# SwiftUI Settings window - change style

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui

Is it possible to somehow change the Settings window style? The code below works for normal windows but does not affect the `Settings` window for some reason.

```swift
Settings {

}
.windowStyle(.titleBar)
.windowToolbarStyle(.unified)
```

or

```swift
Settings {
    MyView()
        .windowStyle(.titleBar)
        .windowToolbarStyle(.unified)
}
```

https://github.com/martinlexow/SwiftUIWindowStyles

[image]

Comment: Right-click on "Settings" in Xcode to see the documentation for Settings. Settings takes a view as an argument which will allow your App struct to create the settings View and attach it to the appropriate menu commands. That View can have the modifiers to make it look how you like.

Comment: yes, but the modifiers are ignored.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible using the underlying [NSWindow](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nswindow):

```swift
Settings {
    MyView()
        .task {
            let window = NSApplication.shared.keyWindow
            window?.toolbarStyle = .unified
            window?.toolbar?.displayMode = .iconOnly
        }
}
```

When opening the settings window for the first time, the "normal" design is visible for a brief moment, so it probably isn't the cleanest solution.